# About the existence of bijections between $(0,1)^{r}$ and $ℝ^{r}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I know that there is some bijections between the open unit interval $(0,1)$ and $ℝ$. My **question** is about the existence of bijections between $(0,1)^{r}$ and $ℝ^{r}$ for $r∈ℕ$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, let $\phi(x)$ be a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ that is $\phi:(0,1)\to \Bbb R$. What can you say about
$$
  \phi_n:(0,1)^n\to \Bbb R^n
$$
defined as $  \phi_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) := (\phi(x_1),\dots,\phi(x_n))$?

Comment: Yes, this construction give a the required bijection.

Comment: @Chaos: indeed, so you're done.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: However Ilya's one is a straightforward way , please let us to have your approach visible here. It embellishes the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Asaf: I support Babak - I don't see a reason why your deleted yours answer. Using $|\Bbb R^n| = |\Bbb R|$?

Comment: @Babak, Ilya: I don't think it's a good answer because it requires knowing that $\Bbb R$ is equipotent with $\Bbb R^r$, and by that point you already know enough basic cardinal arithmetics to derive this result immediately yourself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks anyway. Of course, we can read it visible. ;-) and +1 for Ilya.